# Is it possible to have a complete custom renderHTML function in TipTap?

Tags: tiptap, prose-mirror

Currently the format is like this:

```
renderHTML({ HTMLAttributes }) {
    return ['img', mergeAttributes(this.options.HTMLAttributes, HTMLAttributes)];
  },
```

Now could I do something like this:

```
renderHTML({ HTMLAttributes }) {
    return <div>hello</div>;
  },
```

### Updated with addNodeView:

So I have now a CustomImage.js:

```
const CustomImage = Image.extend({
  addNodeView() {
    return ReactNodeViewRenderer(NextImage);
  },
});
export default CustomImage;
```

And NextImage is:

```
const NextImage = () => {
  return (
    <NodeViewWrapper>
      <div>hello</div>
    </NodeViewWrapper>
  );
};

export default NextImage;
```

And I use it like this:

```
html = generateHTML(JSON.parse(text), [
        CustomImage
   ....
```

Comment: `generateHTML` is a function that goes from tiptap JSON format to html, and will just run render html. I doubt that you have everything in tiptap node format. 
You should rally use the `useEditor` hook. See answer for code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `renderHtml`function is called when you run `editor.getHTML()`

To answer your question, from my best knowledge it need to match their format. To achieve what you want you could do something like this:

```js
renderHTML({ HTMLAttributes }) {
    // On output
    return [
      "div",
      mergeAttributes(HTMLAttributes), // mergeAttributes is a exported function from @tiptap/core
      "hello",
    ];
  },
```

If you on the other hand want to render that in the editor you should use:

```js
addNodeView() {
    return ReactNodeViewRenderer(YourComponentHere);
  },
```

And you can show whatever component you want:

```js
import { NodeViewWrapper } from "@tiptap/react";
import React from "react";

const YourComponentHere = ({ node, updateAttributes, selected, editor }) => {
  return (
    <NodeViewWrapper>
      <div>hello</div>
    </NodeViewWrapper>
  );
};
```

Edit:
Assuming that you are using react, you should use useEditor if you want to use the tiptap editor.

```js
import { useEditor, EditorContent } from '@tiptap/react'
import StarterKit from '@tiptap/starter-kit'
import CustomImage from './CustomImage'

const Tiptap = () => {
  const editor = useEditor({
    extensions: [
      StarterKit,
      CustomImage
    ],
    content: '<p>Your inital content here</p>',
  })

  return (
    <EditorContent editor={editor} />
  )
}

export default Tiptap
```

https://tiptap.dev/installation/react

Comment: So I added your bit of code you suggested to my CustomImage extension (which extends Image) and added a console.log(1) into addNodeView but its not called?

Comment: Update you question with the full code. 
Did som test locally addNodeView() only run when you load that node type in the initial content. However if everything is configured, you should be able to add a console.log in the component and see that it rerenders

Comment: Alright updated